# Morris Donut chart no data issue

Tags: javascript, raphael, morris.js

I am trying to plot some data correctly with Morris Charts using Donut shape.

```
Morris.Donut({
        element: 'donut-chart-revenue',
        data: [],
      });
```

but since the data variable can sometimes be empty (new user , no enough data) the donut shape breaks and i'm having a void placeholder !

How can i sort the problem or replace the placeholder with some text like "No enough data" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not being very familiar with Morris, I suspect you could get away with this:

```
 var data = []; // <-- your empty set

 Morris.Donut({
   element: 'donut-example',
   data: data.length ? data : [ { label:"No Data", value:100 } ]
 });
```

If the length of that data array, wherever it comes from, is empty (data.length == 0), then it'll use that "No Data" array.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I could solve it like this:

```
var donut = null;    

this.init = (function() {

    ...

    donut = Morris.Donut({
        element : 'id-div',
        data : [{ label:"no data", value:100 }],
        colors : [ '#E6A548', '#1CC09f', '#FB5651', '#1CC09f', '#63A3DF', '#999' ],
    });
});

this.find = (function() {


    $.ajax() ... {

        if (dados.length == 0) {
            dados.push({ label:"no data", value:100 });
        }

        donut.setData(dados);
        donut.redraw();

    }
});
```

Using:

```
data : [{ label:"no data", value:100 }],
```

and

```
dados.push({ label:"no data", value:100 });
```

when you do not have data